# Running Ray in docker

Tags: python, ray

I'm trying to run `ray` in a docker image that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.10.5-bullseye

RUN pip install -U "ray[default]==2.6.3"
...

CMD ["ray", "start", "--head", "--block", "--include-dashboard=false"]
```

After starting the container as a first test I want to run a sample job inside of the docker container.

So from a shell in the docker container this is what I've tried:

```
# 1
ray job submit --working-dir . -- python scripts/verify_ray.py
# 2
RAY_ADDRESS='http://127.0.0.1:8265' ray job submit --working-dir . -- python scripts/verify_ray.py 
# 3
RAY_ADDRESS='http://192.168.65.4:8265' ray job submit --working-dir . -- python scripts/verify_ray.py # I got this addr from the log ie "Local node IP: 192.168.65.4"
```

Which all had a connection errors:

```
raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to Ray at address: http://127.0.0.1:8265.

raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to Ray at address: http://127.0.0.1:8265.

raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to Ray at address: http://192.168.65.4:8265.
```

Logs and `ray status` look good:

```
# ray status
======== Autoscaler status: 2023-08-28 13:43:03.538505 ========
Node status
---------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy:
 1 node_47d1ee6b471a183a6de153cda4bb81dfb8bf4a0ad174c4bac0ed9010
Pending:
 (no pending nodes)
Recent failures:
 (no failures)

Resources
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
 0.0/8.0 CPU
 0B/3.30GiB memory
 0B/1.65GiB object_store_memory

Demands:
 (no resource demands)
```

Anyone have any ideas what I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This works:
`CMD ["ray", "start", "--head", "--block"]`

ie removing the `--include-dashboard=false`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Add the ports you want to open in the docker file. To DOCKERFILE add

```
EXPOSE 8265
```

Comment: I'm running this from inside the docker container so I don't believe this is the issue.  (But I did try it and it didn't work)